# css background-image coordinates - what tool to use?

Tags: css, image

Looking at the following image:

[image]

What tool should I use to get the coordinates of the image section that I want, so that I can use it for example in:

```
.myimage {
    background-position: -283px -64px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a non-visual grid and place each image in the top left corner of the grid. For example alle fields would be 16 by 16 pixels - then you could calculate the coordinates by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly any image editor or viewer. Even MS Paint (in Windows 7) will show the coordinates with the Select tool in the lower left.

Answer (score 3):

Try this online tool: http://www.spritecow.com/ 
Open you png picture, just select the icon, sprite css will be generated automaticly

Answer (score 1):

If each image were already an exported png or jpg, you could use a tool like [locator.codestrict.com](https://locator.codestrict.com/) to output  the coordinates automatically.

You just choose your background image and the cropped images you want to locate and the css top/left is will display. Of course, you'd just have to translate top/left to background-position.